# Styles didn't apply to Django Project when uploaded to Render

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, django

I tried to upload my django project to Render which contains plenty of HTML files as well CSS styles. The latter is used in a CSS file called 'styles.css' within the static folder. When I run the project, the images are shown, but it's like the styles have not been applied to everything, not even the Django Admin panel. On the console, it mentioned something about how the stylesheet wasn't loaded because of MIME type. The same happens with my main.js file, which is also within the static folder. I have heard about using gunicorn, which I have it installed, but i'm not sure if it's actually responsible for causing this since the images load fine (although their sizes are very much different). I want to know if there's a solution to this.

For reference, this is how I added the urls of my media and static in the settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

This is my current urls.py for my main project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls')),
    path('chatbot/', include('chatbot.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The base.html I am using, which contains links and scripts tags in its header, is this:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <!-- custom css & js -->
  <script src="{% static 'main.js' %}" defer></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>U-Community Mart</title>

</head>


<body class="body-main">
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" id="message" role="alert">
          {{message}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

UPDATE: I tried installing whitenoise, as well as making some other additions mainly in the settings.py file.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if not DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I also added 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware' just after the SecurityMiddleware. As of now, the django admin panel now loads the correct styles. However, i am still having problems with trying to load the css and js files. These are the changes I made in the html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
  <script src="static/main.js" defer></script>
```

I really think the issue has to be the urls, but I still don't know how to fix it.

UPDATE 2: I managed to solve it. Apparently, from what I learned, Render accesses all static files of the project in another folder called 'staticfiles'. While I had that folder, there was nothing in it. What I had to do was to add this is the settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if not DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 
    'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Then run python manage.py collectstatic. Now all the static files are inside the folder that Render needed to use. Still I appreciate any responses made on here. Hope this might also be useful for anyone considering on deploying their django project on Render.

Comment: Where is STATIC_ROOT setting? Show us full settings.py.

Comment: {Styles didn't apply to Django Project when uploaded to Render} what do mean by uploaded to runder?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try removing the backslash "/" which is placed inside the STATIC_URL in the starting in the second last code block you given. Because in the first code block I saw:

```py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

When we compare to second last code block:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Also I compared it to my own projects, the line should be:

```py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```